# Wordpress IIS intranet server

Tags: localhost, iis

I am using microsoft's IIS (Internet Information Service) software to host a wordpress server, this works well by going to localhost but I can not get it to work so I can type in my computer's IP on another computer on the network and load that website (can do it on my computer either).

Anyone know how to fix this? I need it for an upcoming LAN party me and some friends are hosting.
Also does anyone know how/if I can use OBS to stream directly to a local server/website, because I would like to for the LAN (as stated earlier) to do a spectator view + commentary.

(Side note: All above must be able to run without internet completely)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have opened port 80 on your local firewall?

This doen't answer your question directly but might be quicker and easier to set up based on the time limits you have. You can try installing a server technology called Apache it is packaged into [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html).

I have had more success with Apache out of the box than IIS.

I'll be able to provide a guide for WordPress via IIS on Windows 10 later when I get home.

Comment: XAMPP doesn't work on my computer properly

Comment: When I run my website I use Microsoft Web Matrix through IIS, which sets up my website under the port 42784. When I port forward either 80 or 42784 and go to [my local ip]:[80 or 42784] I get the error "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid."

Comment: I think this question would be better suited to ServerFault. There are more fundamental network/configuration issues unrelated to WordPress.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that was a stackexchange, so I just went for wordpress because that was related.